# Deleting node from linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm trying understand deleting nodes from linked lists, so I made the function `Node *deleteNode(int item. Node *head)` shown below.  It does delete a node, but not the one I specified in my main function.  If I start with a linked lsit of (1,2,3,4,5,6), it returns a list of (1,3,4,5,6). So it always deletes the 2nd node for some reason. What is the error in my deleteNode function that is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? Hint `=` is not the same as `==`

Comment: Also, in `deleteNode` you never modify `head`.  So what happens when you try to delete the head of your list?  You will return the same `head` as before (the node you just deleted).  You need to handle the case where you delete the head of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to really think over how your list operates in order to delete a node. I would definitely consider removing several pieces from your deleteNode so that it will flow smoother. Please consider the following:

```
Node *deleteNode(int item, Node *head){
    Node * current = head, *pTemp = NULL, *pPrev = NULL;

while((current->link->info != item) && ((current -> link != NULL)) //You want to traverse the list until you find the item.
{      
  pPrev = current; // Assign previous pointer which is null to head of list and so on.
  current = current->link // Assign current pointer to next node.
}

if (current->link-> info == item )
{
  pTemp = current; // Assign temp pointer to current pointer
  current = pTemp->link; // set current to next pointer
  pPrev->link = current; // set previous pointer to current
  free (pTemp)
}
else
{
 // Did not find at all in list.
}

return head;
```

}

This is all generalized and on the fly, please debug your code and write on paper the structure of your list.

Answer (score 0):

With linked-lists and fumbling around with the pointers and nodes, its very important that you know which pointer points to what, and whats the general layout of your linked lists. When I try to explain it to someone I often draw a painting on my whiteboard. Just draw a small diagram with some nodes and the pointers connecting them. In this way you see very fast which pointers you have to redirect to other nodes in order to remove a node from the list.

in short: With a drawing its very clear what to do and the coding isn't hard actually if you know what to do.